# How to hide implicit parameters in the middle on apply chain

Tags: scala, implicit

Reduced example:

```
class Factory(x : Int) {
  def apply(y : Int)(z : Int) : Int = x + y + z
}

class Sample {
  def get[B <% Int](x : B) = new Factory(x)
}

val s = new Sample
```

What I want: `s.get(2)(3)(4)` should output `9`. What I get

```
error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(3)
 required: Int => Int
       s.get(2)(3)(4)
                ^
```

It is perfectly correct, compiler fails as it should. The second parameter list should contain implicit conversion, but it is omitted. Hence the error arises.

The question is how to make the compiler know that is should perform implicit resolution.

Things I've tried that does not work:

- `s.get(2)()(3)(4)`
- `{s get 2}(3)(4)`
- `(s get 2)(3)(4)`
- `((s get 2))(3)(4)`

Explicit way works, but it requires two lines instead of one:

```
val b = s get 2
b(3)(4)
```

I could also use the `apply` method explicitly: `s.get(2).apply(3)(4)` But it looks ugly.

How can I make compiler perform implicit resolution inside an expression?

Comment: View  bounds `<%` have been deprecated.  Change that to `<:` and it works (at least it compiles and runs for me).

Comment: It is a model example. Real program could not work without implicit conversions. `<%` is still not deprecated. When it would be, I would study carefully whatever alternative suggested to replace this construction

Comment: @ayvango an example i met recently: `implicit val s = "ss"; def g(implicit s: String) = Map.empty[Int, String]; g(3)` will not compile.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an explicit type ascription

```
val nine = (s.get(2): Factory)(3)(4)
```

Or if you find this inconvenient, build your own control structure for forcing type inference:

```
def infer[X](z: => X): X = z
val nineAgain = infer(s get 2)(3)(4)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s.get(2)(implicitly)(3)(4)
```

(`implicitly` is just a method defined in `Predef`: `def implicitly[A](implicit x: A) = x`.)